# How is the type for a sorted list defined in type theory?

Tags: type-theory

I am trying to figure out what the constructor and eliminator would look like for a type representing "sorted list"?

Comment: It's not that hard for most programming language with a reasonable type system, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031572/sorted-array-list-in-java) is perhaps the most easiest implementation in Java. Of course you can go fancy and use dependent type theory with programing language such as Idris and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105461/sorted-list-in-idris-insertion-sort) is such an example.

Comment: Constructors and eliminators are only postulated for basic type formers. The type of sorted lists is a composite of those, so it won't have immediate constructors and eliminators. Instead you can use the corresponding ones of the types that comprise the sorted list type.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm sorry, since I'm new to type theory I got a bit confused. Does that mean the sorted list type also has constructor and eliminator but we need to create some intermediary types that will be used in sorted lists constructor and eliminator?! Would you please elaborate a bit further?